# Prove that $a^2+ab+b^2\geq 0$ for all $a,b$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Prove that $a^2+ab+b^2\geq 0$ for all $a,b$. My attempt

I supossed by contradiction that exist $a,b$ such that $a^2+b^2<-ab$ then $a^2+2ab+b^2\leq ab$ implies that
$(a+b)^2\leq ab$ therefore $a+b<\sqrt{ab}$ but
$\sqrt{ab}\leq \frac{a+b}{2}$ then $a+b<\frac{a+b}{2}$ contradiction.

Is fine my proof? Or exist other form to show. Thank you

Comment: @user The proof is valid only for $a \geq 0 $and $b \geq 0$. If $a<0$ and $b<0$ then $ab \geq 0$ is true but the step $\sqrt{ab} \leq \frac{a+b}{2}$ (AM-GM) is not true.

Comment: thank you @ascheper!!

Comment: @aschepler Yes of course! thanks

Comment: When you assume $(a+b)^2 \le ab \implies a+b \le \sqrt {ab}$ you are assuming that $ab \ge 0$ and that $a + b\ge 0$.  In assume $\sqrt{ab}\le \frac {a+b}2$ you are assuming $a,b > 0$.  None of these are given.  But you are on the way.  Note: $0 \le a^2 + b^2 <-ab \implies ab< 0$.  Then $a^2+2ab + b^2 \le ab\implies (a+b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2 \le ab < 0$ which *is* a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

$$a^2+b^2+ab=\frac{1}{2}[(a+b)^2+(a-b)^2]+\frac{1}{4}[(a+b)^2-(a-b)^2]=\frac{3}{4}(a+b)^2+\frac{1}{4}(a-b)^2 \ge 0$$

Answer (score 1):

$a^2+ab+b^2= (a+b)^2-ab.$ If $a$ and $b$ have opposite sign, or at least one is $0,$ the result is obvious since the right-hand side will be nonnegative. If $a$ and $b$ have the same sign, there is no harm assuming both are positive. But then the left-hand side of the equality is positive, and you are done.

Or, notice $|ab| \leq \mathrm{max}\{a^2,b^2\},$ so either $a^2+ab$ or $b^2+ab$ is nonnegative (even if $ab$ is negative) and you're done.